# How to filter products using javascript?

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm unable to make this filter work properly.

All I want is if someone clicks on a particular filter, the products underneath gets sorted accordingly.
I have used data-* attributes for filtering.

HTML:

```html
<section id="store" class="store py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- section title -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10 mx-auto col-sm-6 text-center">
          <h1 class="text-capitalize">our <strong class="banner-title ">store</strong></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end of section title -->
      <!--filter buttons -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-lg-8 mx-auto d-flex justify-content-around my-2 sortBtn flex-wrap">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-black text-uppercase filter-btn m-2" data-filter="all" onclick="filterItems(this)"> all</a>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-black text-uppercase filter-btn m-2" data-filter="cakes" onclick="filterItems(this)">cakes</a>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-black text-uppercase filter-btn m-2" data-filter="cupcakes" onclick="filterItems(this)">cupcakes</a>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-black text-uppercase filter-btn m-2" data-filter="sweets" onclick="filterItems(this)">sweets</a>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-black text-uppercase filter-btn m-2" data-filter="doughnuts" onclick="filterItems(this)">doughnuts</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--end of filter buttons -->
      <!-- store  items-->
      <div class="row" id="store-items">
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item sweets" data-item="sweets">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="https://js-beginners.github.io/filter-project/img/sweets-1.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">sweet item</h5>
                <p class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">5</strong></p>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item cupcakes" data-item="cupcakes">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="https://js-beginners.github.io/filter-project/img/cupcake-1.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">cupcake item</h5>
                <p class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">5</strong></p>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item cakes" data-item="cakes">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="https://js-beginners.github.io/filter-project/img/cake-1.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">cake item</h5>
                <p class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">5</strong></p>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item doughnuts" data-item="dougnuts">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="https://js-beginners.github.io/filter-project/img/doughnut-1.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">dougnut item</h5>
                <p class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">5</strong></p>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item sweets" data-item="sweets">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="https://js-beginners.github.io/filter-project/img/sweets-2.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">sweet item</h5>
                <p class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">10</strong></p>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item cupcakes" data-item="cupcakes">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="https://js-beginners.github.io/filter-project/img/cupcake-2.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">cupcake item</h5>
                <p class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">10</strong></p>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item cakes" data-item="cakes">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="https://js-beginners.github.io/filter-project/img/cake-2.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">cake item</h5>
                <p class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">10</strong></p>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item doughnuts" data-item="dougnuts">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="https://js-beginners.github.io/filter-project/img/doughnut-2.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">dougnut item</h5>
                <p class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">10</strong></p>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item sweets" data-item="sweets">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="https://js-beginners.github.io/filter-project/img/sweets-3.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">sweet item</h5>
                <p class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">15</strong></p>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item cupcakes" data-item="cupcakes">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="https://js-beginners.github.io/filter-project/img/cupcake-3.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">cupcake item</h5>
                <p class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">15</strong></p>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item cakes" data-item="cakes">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="https://js-beginners.github.io/filter-project/img/cake-3.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">cake item</h5>
                <p class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">15</strong></p>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item doughnuts" data-item="dougnuts">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="https://js-beginners.github.io/filter-project/img/doughnut-3.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">dougnut item</h5>
                <p class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">15</strong></p>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->

      </div>
  </section>
```

JS:

```js
const storeItems = document.querySelectorAll('.store-item');
const filterBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-btn');

function filterItems(){
  filterBtn.forEach(function(btn){
    const filter = btn.dataset.filter;
    if (filter === "all"){
      console.log(filter);
      storeItems.forEach(function(item){
        item.style.display = "block"
      })
    }
    else if (filter === "cakes"){
      console.log(filter);
      storeItems.forEach(function(item){
        if (item.classList.contains('cakes')){
          item.style.display = "block"
        }
        else {
          item.style.display = "none"
        }
      })
    }
    else if (filter === "cupcakes"){
      console.log(filter);
      storeItems.forEach(function(item){
        if (item.classList.contains('cupcakes')){
          item.style.display = "block"
        }
        else {
          item.style.display = "none"
        }
      })
    }
    else if (filter === "sweets"){
      console.log(filter);
      storeItems.forEach(function(item){
        if (item.classList.contains('sweets')){
          item.style.display = "block"
        }
        else {
          item.style.display = "none"
        }
      })
    }
    else if (filter === "doughnuts"){
      console.log(filter);
      storeItems.forEach(function(item){
        if (item.classList.contains('doughnuts')){
          item.style.display = "block"
        }
        else {
          item.style.display = "none"
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

What happens is on clicking on a particular filter button, only the products having `class="doughnuts"` gets displayed and the rest sets to `display:none`.

To better explain there's a demo available here: https://codepen.io/sumayya_ishaq/pen/eYdQaRy

Comment: https://codepen.io/kmsdevnet/pen/MWjLgdO

Comment: In the HTML, data-item="dougnuts" has a misspelling/typo. Correct that and you can focus on the JS.

Comment: yes, got it. Thanks @Remento
I found a solution though and I have updated the codepen link with the same solution

Comment: Thanks @kosmos for your solution too. You helped me make my code efficient.